# Error Msg = ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am trying to pass a LocalDate value in the following native query from a TestController class -

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT SCHED_EVENT.UOID,SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT,SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT_ACTIVITY,SCHED_EVENT.A_EVENT_TYPE , " +
        " SCHED_EVENT.SCHEDULED_DATE,SCHED_EVENT.INVOICE_DUE_DATE,SCHED_EVENT.A_WORK_ITEM,SCHED_EVENT.A_OPER_BK_ORG , "+
        " INSTRUMENT.INSTRUMENT_ID,ACTIVITY.A_ACTIVITY_TYPE,ACTIVITY.SEQ_NUM_OF_ACTV_TY FROM SCHED_EVENT, INSTRUMENT, ACTIVITY "+
        " WHERE SCHED_EVENT.A_EVENT_TYPE = 'PAY' AND SCHED_EVENT.INVOICE_DUE_DATE = :invoiceDueDate "+
        " AND SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT = INSTRUMENT.UOID AND INSTRUMENT.UOID = ACTIVITY.P_INSTRUMENT AND SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT_ACTIVITY = ACTIVITY.UOID "+
        " AND EXISTS (SELECT SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT FROM INSTRUMENT, PARTY, CUSTOMER WHERE SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT = INSTRUMENT.UOID AND (INSTRUMENT.A_PRODUCT = 'ATP') "+
        " AND (INSTRUMENT.A_CLIENT_BANK = 'BMG' OR INSTRUMENT.A_CLIENT_BANK = 'CB1') AND (INSTRUMENT.A_TERMS_ACTIVE = PARTY.P_OBJECT) "+
        " AND (PARTY.RELATION_CUST_IND = 'Y') AND (PARTY.A_CUSTOMER = CUSTOMER.UOID) AND (CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = 'C119001' OR CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = 'C119003'))")
public List<Object[]> getATPPaymentScheduleList(@Param("invoiceDueDate") LocalDate invoiceDueDate);
```

I am passing the date from TestController class as -

```
@Autowired
private ScheduledEventRepository scheduledEventRepository;


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Secure("bank setup")
@ResponseBody
public MappingJacksonValue findByActivityAndAmortAccrue(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String id) {

    List<Object[]> entryList;
    org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yy");
    LocalDate dateTime = new LocalDate();

    entryList = scheduledEventRepository.getATPPaymentScheduleList(dateTime.parse("11-APR-13", fmt));

    return buildResponseView(entryList, id);
}
```

}

When hitting the URL from PostMan, I am getting the following exception -

```
    exceptionMessage:
```

"org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
            "stackTrace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy490.getATPPaymentScheduleList(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)\r\n\tat org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.util.ReloadingProxyFactory$ReloadingMethodHandler.invoke(JRebel:74)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy490.getATPPaymentScheduleList(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.cgi.t360.tps.controller.test.TestController2.findByActivityAndAmortAccrue(TestController2.java:251)\r\n\tat com.cgi.t360.tps.controller.test.TestController2$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ba1b29a4.invoke()\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)\r\n\tat com.cgi.t360.tps.aspects.PerformanceAspect.profile(PerformanceAspect.java:66)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)\r\n\tat com.cgi.t360.tps.controller.test.TestController2$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c3814053.findByActivityAndAmortAccrue()\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)\r\n\tat com.cgi.t360.tps.LogEnhancerFilter.doFilter(LogEnhancerFilter.java:25)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\r\n\tat com.cgi.t360.tps.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:42)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)\r\n\tat org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)\r\n\tat io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)\r\n\tat io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\r\n\tat io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)\r\n\tat io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)\r\n\tat io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)\r\n\tat io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)\r\n\tat io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\r\n\tat org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)\r\n\tat io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\r\n\tat io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.jrHandle(ServletInitialHandler.java)\r\n\tat org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.servlet.undertow.cbp.ServletInitialHandlerCBP.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandlerCBP.java:98)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)\r\n\tat io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175)\r\n\tat io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:209)\r\n\tat io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:802)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2117)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1900)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:110)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:74)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:90)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:415)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:393)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:506)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)\r\n\t... 92 more\r\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY\n\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:747)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822)\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)\r\n\tat org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:504)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)\r\n\t... 121 more\r\nCaused by: Error : 932, Position : 402, Sql = SELECT SCHED_EVENT.UOID,SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT,SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT_ACTIVITY,SCHED_EVENT.A_EVENT_TYPE ,  SCHED_EVENT.SCHEDULED_DATE,SCHED_EVENT.INVOICE_DUE_DATE,SCHED_EVENT.A_WORK_ITEM,SCHED_EVENT.A_OPER_BK_ORG ,  INSTRUMENT.INSTRUMENT_ID,ACTIVITY.A_ACTIVITY_TYPE,ACTIVITY.SEQ_NUM_OF_ACTV_TY FROM SCHED_EVENT, INSTRUMENT, ACTIVITY  WHERE SCHED_EVENT.A_EVENT_TYPE = 'PAY' AND SCHED_EVENT.INVOICE_DUE_DATE = :1   AND SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT = INSTRUMENT.UOID AND INSTRUMENT.UOID = ACTIVITY.P_INSTRUMENT AND SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT_ACTIVITY = ACTIVITY.UOID  AND EXISTS (SELECT SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT FROM INSTRUMENT, PARTY, CUSTOMER WHERE SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT = INSTRUMENT.UOID AND (INSTRUMENT.A_PRODUCT = 'ATP')  AND (INSTRUMENT.A_CLIENT_BANK = 'BMG' OR INSTRUMENT.A_CLIENT_BANK = 'CB1') AND (INSTRUMENT.A_TERMS_ACTIVE = PARTY.P_OBJECT)  AND (PARTY.RELATION_CUST_IND = 'Y') AND (PARTY.A_CUSTOMER = CUSTOMER.UOID) AND (CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = 'C119001' OR CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = 'C119003')), OriginalSql = SELECT SCHED_EVENT.UOID,SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT,SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT_ACTIVITY,SCHED_EVENT.A_EVENT_TYPE ,  SCHED_EVENT.SCHEDULED_DATE,SCHED_EVENT.INVOICE_DUE_DATE,SCHED_EVENT.A_WORK_ITEM,SCHED_EVENT.A_OPER_BK_ORG ,  INSTRUMENT.INSTRUMENT_ID,ACTIVITY.A_ACTIVITY_TYPE,ACTIVITY.SEQ_NUM_OF_ACTV_TY FROM SCHED_EVENT, INSTRUMENT, ACTIVITY  WHERE SCHED_EVENT.A_EVENT_TYPE = 'PAY' AND SCHED_EVENT.INVOICE_DUE_DATE = ?  AND SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT = INSTRUMENT.UOID AND INSTRUMENT.UOID = ACTIVITY.P_INSTRUMENT AND SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT_ACTIVITY = ACTIVITY.UOID  AND EXISTS (SELECT SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT FROM INSTRUMENT, PARTY, CUSTOMER WHERE SCHED_EVENT.A_OBJECT = INSTRUMENT.UOID AND (INSTRUMENT.A_PRODUCT = 'ATP')  AND (INSTRUMENT.A_CLIENT_BANK = 'BMG' OR INSTRUMENT.A_CLIENT_BANK = 'CB1') AND (INSTRUMENT.A_TERMS_ACTIVE = PARTY.P_OBJECT)  AND (PARTY.RELATION_CUST_IND = 'Y') AND (PARTY.A_CUSTOMER = CUSTOMER.UOID) AND (CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = 'C119001' OR CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = 'C119003')), Error Msg = ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got BINARY\n\r\n\tat oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)\r\n\t... 137 more\r\n"

I have tried passing date in multiple formats but nothing worked. The data type of SCHED_EVENT.INVOICE_DUE_DATE in database is Date.

What is the correct way to pass the date here ?

Answer (score 0):

Error message is talling you that your sql request expecting to see `Date` as parameter but you put `LocalDate` instead, so to fix this you should convert your `LocalDate` value to `Date`.

Comment: Could you please suggest how I do that ?

Comment: You can use this : 
`Date date = Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());`